# How to have the example Spring application use Gradle (instead of / as well as Maven)

Tags: np-spring

The [example Spring application](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/np-spring-tutorial) is now using Maven as its build tool. Liked to get some suggestion on what would be the easiest way support Gradle as well, assuming both Gradle and Maven scripts can reside and work in the same project. If both Gradle and Maven can't work together, what would be the easiest way to migrate the project to Gradle?

It uses JSP, and has a WAR packaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle and Maven are two different dependency management systems. Of course you can reside two scripts into a single project. There should be no problem if no more decision has been made by IDE. In other words, which system should be used is up to you.

The meaningful way to know how to use Gradle in spring project is to generate a gradle project through `Spring Initializizr`([link](https://start.spring.io/)).

You need specify the project type by select `Maven Project` or `Gradle Project` and `Spring Boot` version and other dependencies according to the origin maven project. It could be easy.

[image]

Then gradle documentation should be useful([link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes)). However, if you just want to use its simple features, it's enough to read the content generated by `Spring Initializr`.

Other questions you can google it or post it in stackoverflow.

I believe you'll get much more familiar about `Gradle` by trying it yourself. Good luck!